# win 7 hangs on restart because of tascam audio interface

Tags: windows, windows-7, usb, device-driver

In xp, my Tascam US 122 usb audio interface works fine.

On my windows 7 computer the device works, however when i restart/shutdown it hangs at the "shutting down" screen forever.

If the usb cable is removed prior to initiating restart/shutdown then everything goes fine, the computer restarts as normal.

This is a known problem, running any other driver in compatibility mode doesnt fix the problem.

Is there a method I can use to unload the device/drivers so that I dont have to reach round physically and disconnect the cable. Somebody suggested a spdt switch on the cable itself, but I am looking for a simpler method. Surely I can automate the unloading of the device through a script or such?

Any ideas are greatly welcomed thanks

Comment: http://www.superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device has its own driver perhaps you can try shutting down the driver service.